# Laravel notifications - Mailgun - "On Behalf of" in Outlook

Tags: php, laravel, email, outlook, mailgun

The sender in mails recieved in MS. Outlook, sent thru mailgun api looks like this:

**info=domain.com@mg.domain.com on behalf of info@domain.com**

Using `->from` (as suggested in the documentation) does **not** solve it:

```
return (new MailMessage)->from('info@domain.com', 'Domain.com')
```

**When sending a traditional `Mail::send()` I solve it by...**

...adding `->sender('info@domain.com', 'Mr Info')` to the class:

```
 Mail::send(['html' => 'emails.my-email'], ['data' => $this->details], function ($message) use ($details) {
            $message->to($details['email']);
            $message->from(config('mail.from.address'), config('mail.from.name'));
            $message->sender(config('mail.from.address'), config('mail.from.name'));
        });
```

However I can't figure out how I add the `->sender()` class to notifications...?

Laravel 8

Comment: Have you verified domain on mailgun?

Comment: hehe sure - it is verified. 
I can send mails thru `Mail::send` with accurate sender describtion in outlook. (This thanks to that I have added the ->sender class).